# Axis 2: what does InvocationResponse.SUSPEND do?

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

If you specify a custom Handler to return this, what does it do? Does it pause the chain/flow? If so, by how long? How does it affect the flow overall? CONTINUE, and ABORT are fairly self-explanatory, but this response I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the details of the each status of handler returns inside axis engine.

(1) InvocationResponse.CONTINUE

This gives the signal to continue the message execution flow.

(2) InvocationResponse.SUSPEND

This denotes that the message cannot continue as some of the conditions are not satisfied yet, so you need to pause the execution and wait.

For example, there can be a handler which suspends the execution and store the message context, and when the conditions are satisfied, forward the message.
The best example for this is Reliable Messaging (RM),it works on the message sequence. If a service invocation consists of more than one message, and
if the second one comes before the first, RM handler will pause the execution of the message invocation corresponding to the second message until it
gets the first message. When it gets the first message, RM will invoke that, and then after that, it will invoke (or resume) the second message and etc.

So the time period for suspension will be until the pre/post conditions met,as explained in RM scenario.

(3) InvocationResponse.ABORT

Something has gone wrong, therefore you need to drop the message and let the initiator know about it

Comment: So does this mean that when a Handler returns `InvocationResponse.SUSPEND`, the operation is suspended indefinitely until another message is received? Aside from receiving another message, what other possible events could trigger resumption of operation?

Comment: In RM scenario, it waits till next sequence message comes in, if no message as expected then InactivityTimeout will reach and then clean up the flow, in our RM scenario there is no meaning to resume the flow if no preconditions are met, like message sequence expected. Hope you go the idea.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got the idea of RM. I'm just trying to understand how the actual implementation would be like. How would another operation be able to tell a previously suspended operation to resume? What represents an operation in the first place: A thread, a persistent `MessageContext`, etc.?

Comment: Handler is saving its MessageContext, on next precondition check when new message arrival  it will get this MessageContext and decide next steps.

Comment: Is this done through `AxisEngine`'s `write-`/`readExternal` methods? There are also `get-`/`setSelfManagedData` methods; I wonder if they work similarly.

Comment: MC serialize/deserialize can be done with implementaion of SelfManagedDataManager, http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/context/SelfManagedDataManager.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43763/discussion-between-psycho-punch-and-jayalalk)